# archiving tables that are related to other tables with FK

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, foreign-key

I have a database i need to archive some of its tables leaving always data above 2 years.
some of the tables are related to other tables with FK (about 21 FK tables) , so clearly i cant delete the rows with the PK without deleting the fk related rows.
the process of the archiving was suppose to be inserting the rows to the archiving database and deleting them from the old DB using dynamic SQL. but not with the FK i was wondering what is the best way to handle the archiving of the related tables.
can i do it using dynamic SQL or do i have to compare all the PK IDS from the originals tables and compare them in the related tables move the data from there delete the FK rows and then do the delete for every table?

what is the best approach to deal with that situation?
please let me know if i need to clarify my question.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

We faced exactly the same scenario.  Our solution was to have a SQL Server Agent job with a steps to call stored procs co-ordinating the delete/archive.

To make our lives easier we had the application that persisted the data in the first place write a DateTimeCreated field in each related table with exactly the same date/time.  For example an ProductEnquiry record and associated ProductResults record would get exactly the same date/time.

Our clustered index was on that DateTimeCreated so DELETE FROM ProductResults WHERE DateTimeCreated BETWEEN... made use of the clustered index.

As the database grew we found that the purge jobs had to have a pre/post step to disable/re-enable the FK constraints.

We also had to start using a loop so we purged 50,000 records at a time and kept going until there were no more qualifying records to delete.

When we move to Enterprise edition we started using partition switching which had a dramatic performance improvement on purge activity and massively reduced IO on our SAN.

Comment: thanks dave. in my situation my client doesnt allow me to disable the fk constraints. but he is willing to archive all in the child tables everything related to the pk deleted on the parenta tables.

Comment: i should be able to delete the rows with the pk only if theyre not related with fk in other tables right ? i mean if i delete the fk related rows and then the rows in the parent table i should be fine

Comment: To use an analogy if you have an order_header and order_items then you have to delete the order_items first and then the order_header.  If you have order_header records with no order_items then you can delete the order_header records